# SQL Developer code 'Advanced Format' versus 'Custom Format'

Tags: oracle-sql-developer

Preferences -> Code Editor -> Format -> *Advanced Format*
versus
Preferences -> Code Editor -> Format -> Advanced Format -> *Custom Format*

As I understand, both are alternative options to (re)format code in SQL Developer, where *Advanced Format* bases on .xml and *Custom Format* bases on .prg.

It seems, that the *Advanced Format* is the default, which is used when pushing Ctrl+F7.

How can I deactivate *Advanced Format* and activate *Custom Format* now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom format allows you to augment what's available with GUI controls in the advanced formatter preferences page.

It uses arbori, a parse tree query language.

The developer, Vadim, discusses this in his blog [here](https://vadimtropashko.wordpress.com/2017/09/28/formatting-formulas/).

So you don't pick one or the other - both are in play when using the formatter.